# Variable in constructor undefined before render but visible after

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I use firebase to call for some user data, and store it in an array. Then, when I define the state, I set "noteData" to that array. However, the console.log(this.state.noteData) within the constructor returns "Array[]" and the return method does not display the series of mapped components.

I created a button that runs this.forceUpdate() and then console.log(this.state.noteData), and this causes all the components to render properly, and the console.log() returns all the elements in the array that it should.

I tried using .bind(this) as well as componentWillMounth(), but I cannot figure out how to ensure the state is defined before the render method runs for the first time.

It seems like the render is running before the state has updated, and only re-rendering after the button is pressed will fix it. Additionally, I can press the forceUpdate() button many times right after loading into this screen and nothing will occur until a few seconds after. My guess is that the data is still updating during this time.

```
constructor(props){
super(props);

let returnArr = [];

firebase
  .database()
  .ref('/users/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid + '/notes')
  .once('value')
  .then(snapshot => {

    snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
      let item = childSnapshot.val();
      item.key = childSnapshot.key;

      returnArr.push(item);
    })
  })

this.state = {
  fontPreference: firebase.auth().currentUser.fontPref,
  noteData: returnArr
}

console.log(this.state.noteData);
}

 /* * * forceUpdate() button * * */      
 <TouchableOpacity
     onPress={() => {
           this.forceUpdate();
           console.log(this.state.noteData)
     }}>
 ...

 /* * * within return method of render *  * */
 <ScrollView>
      {this.state.noteData.map(note => {
        return <NotePreview
          navigation = {this.props.navigation}
          currNoteImg={note.noteImg}
          currNoteTxt={note.noteTxt}
          noteId={note.key}
        />
      })}
 </ScrollView>
```

Comment: note we should use set state call back to see the change instantly, since setState() is aync, console after the setState() will not show the data. put you console inside setState call back, like ` this.setState({blah: blah}, ()=> console.log(this.state.blah))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use setState inside  `.then`

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    let returnArr = [];
    // declare default state
    this.state = {
       fontPreference: firebase.auth().currentUser.fontPref,
       noteData: []
    }

    firebase
      .database()
      .ref('/users/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid + '/notes')
      .once('value')
      .then(snapshot => {

        snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
          let item = childSnapshot.val();
          item.key = childSnapshot.key;

          returnArr.push(item);
        })
        // update state
       this.setState({
          noteData: returnArr
       })
    })
}
```

Comment: You should move the this.state down ourt of the promise so that state is not undefined, while the promise is executing. Use setState within then block to push the new data.

Answer (score 0):

Calling a firebase is async operation. So first time render it would be empty array. You should do setState in .then and also set state for first render.

You can also set loading flag so you can show loader and make it false once you get response from server.

```
constructor(props){
super(props);

let returnArr = [];

firebase
  .database()
  .ref('/users/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid + '/notes')
  .once('value')
  .then(snapshot => {

    snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
      let item = childSnapshot.val();
      item.key = childSnapshot.key;

      returnArr.push(item);

      this.setState({noteData: returnArr});
    })
  })

this.state = {
  fontPreference: firebase.auth().currentUser.fontPref,
  noteData: returnArr
}

console.log(this.state.noteData);
}

 /* * * forceUpdate() button * * */      
 <TouchableOpacity
     onPress={() => {
           this.forceUpdate();
           console.log(this.state.noteData)
     }}>
 ...

 /* * * within return method of render *  * */
 <ScrollView>
      {this.state.noteData.map(note => {
        return <NotePreview
          navigation = {this.props.navigation}
          currNoteImg={note.noteImg}
          currNoteTxt={note.noteTxt}
          noteId={note.key}
        />
      })}
 </ScrollView>
```